# how to put fragments with different size inside TabLayout inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, scrollview, android-tablayout

hello I'm  having difficulties in  putting two scrollable fragments in tablayout and using viewpager , inside a main fragment, each fragment in tab layout has different height , but viewpager wont let me use wrap-content and i should set an specific height. 
SO I WANT TO KNOW HOW TO SCROLL MY FRAGMENTS INSIDE TABLAYOUT INSIDE A MAIN FRAGMENT.
here is my screen shots     [SCREEN SHOTS](http://persian-nuts.ir/project/12.png)

here is my main fragment code`

```
  public class BuyerDetailFragment extends Fragment {
  private TextView TextView;
  public static TabLayout tabLayout;
  public static ViewPager viewPager;
  public static int int_items = 2 ;
  private Button request;
  public BuyerDetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buyer_detail,   container, false);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity())
            .setActionBarTitle("مشخصات");
    TextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    request=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    request.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5896E2"));
    request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create custom dialog object
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            // Include dialog.xml file
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.request_dialog);
            // Set dialog title
            dialog.setTitle("درخواست بازدید ملک");


            // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Button acceptButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button6);
            // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close dialog
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"درخواست فرستاده شد",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    String content = getString(R.string.about_house);
    Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(content);
    TextView.setText(html);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    /**
     *Set an Apater for the View Pager
     */
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    /**
     * Now , this is a workaround ,
     * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
     * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
     */

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return new ImagesFragment();
            case 1 : return new ReviewFragment();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
     */

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "تصاویر";
            case 1 :
                return "نقد و بررسی";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

`

here is my main fragment xml code:`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ededed">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="right" />


<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:siBorderWidth="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/image4"
     android:src="@drawable/android2"
     app:siBorderColor="@color/darkgray"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"

            android:text="عنوان اینجا"
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView21"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:text="اتاق"
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="|"
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView24"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#969696"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="درخواست بازدید"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/image4"
            android:background="#76ee26"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/image4" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="۱۲"
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView25"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView24" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:text="سرویس"
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView25" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:text="۱۲"
            android:id="@+id/textView27"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView26"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="|"
            android:id="@+id/textView28"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView26"
            android:textColor="#969696"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:text="  متر مربع  "
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView28" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:text="۳۰۰"
            android:id="@+id/textView30"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView29"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tabsRelative">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:background="@color/textColorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#0b0b0b"
        app:tabTextColor="#707070"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        app:tabBackground="@color/graybackground"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView31"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="#ededed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView31"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>`
```

and her is one of my fragments `

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

<ScrollView 
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



  <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/rl"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">



   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="نقد و بررسی راجع به   ملک"
    android:id="@+id/textView34"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

     <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView34"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="راه های دسترسی"
        android:id="@+id/textView43"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="تیپ محله"
        android:id="@+id/textView44"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="يك خانه 35-30 ساله در منطقه قيطريه كه زماني لوكيشن فيلمبرداري يكي از كارهاي سروش صحت بوده، حالا خانه رؤيايي مهراب قاسم‌خاني، شقايق دهقان و پسرشان نويان است. «دور تا دور خانه قبلي‌مان را برج ساخته بودند. نه نور داشتيم، نه تلويزيون چيزي مي‌گرفت و نه موبايل آنتن مي‌داد. يك پاسيوي دو در دو داشتيم كه نصفش را ماشين لباسشويي گرفته بود. من ته يك سبد رخت چرك را بريده بودم و با ميخ به ديوار زده بودمش و سبد بسكتبال شده بود. "
        android:id="@+id/textView45"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="يك خانه 35-30 ساله در منطقه قيطريه كه زماني لوكيشن فيلمبرداري يكي از كارهاي سروش صحت بوده، حالا خانه رؤيايي مهراب قاسم‌خاني، شقايق دهقان و پسرشان نويان است. «دور تا دور خانه قبلي‌مان را برج ساخته بودند. نه نور داشتيم، نه تلويزيون چيزي مي‌گرفت و نه موبايل آنتن مي‌داد. يك پاسيوي دو در دو داشتيم كه نصفش را ماشين لباسشويي گرفته بود. من ته يك سبد رخت چرك را بريده بودم و با ميخ به ديوار زده بودمش و سبد بسكتبال شده بود. "
        android:id="@+id/textView46"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="همسایه ها"
    android:id="@+id/textView47"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="يك خانه 35-30 ساله در منطقه قيطريه كه زماني لوكيشن فيلمبرداري يكي از كارهاي سروش صحت بوده، حالا خانه رؤيايي مهراب قاسم‌خاني، شقايق دهقان و پسرشان نويان است. «دور تا دور خانه قبلي‌مان را برج ساخته بودند. نه نور داشتيم، نه تلويزيون چيزي مي‌گرفت و نه موبايل آنتن مي‌داد. يك پاسيوي دو در دو داشتيم كه نصفش را ماشين لباسشويي گرفته بود. من ته يك سبد رخت چرك را بريده بودم   و با ميخ به ديوار زده بودمش و سبد بسكتبال شده بود. "
    android:id="@+id/textView48"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView47"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView48"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView48" />

     </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside TABLAYOUT Add a scroll view. And then put your inner fragment inside the scroll view.

Comment: you mean put viewpager inside scroll view?

Comment: In your fragment layout, add a scroll view under the root layout of fragment. and then add the contents inside the scroll view.

Comment: they are there , my root layout is relative layout

Comment: no this is my original code, it didnt insert properly. now it is what i have

Comment: I have edited your code in fragment layout. check at it.

Comment: its like the gray part in the SCREEN SHOTS is not accessible for scrolling

Comment: I got it.. Inside Scroll view make linear layout instead of relative layout.

Comment: which scroll view do you mean?

Comment: In Second layout file, there is a scroll view.

Comment: where r u replacing your fragment in first layout file? Tablayout of viewpager?

Comment: This is the final way.. Add following code into tablayout and viewpager. android:isScrollContainer="true"

Comment: Hey @persian.. Your question solved or not? If Yes, Mark my answer as accepted answer. Else Reply with your doubts.

Comment: no its not solved and the main problem is still there